# Java Repository Query findAll() given an ID from another class (Foreign-Key)

Tags: java, spring-boot, rest, jpa, crud

I'm using a JPARepository called **PublicationRepository** and want to find all **Publications** from a certain **Person**. This Classes are connected over the Class **Author**.

Person Class:

```
@Entity
public class Person {

        @Id
        private String email;
    
        private String telefon;
    
        private String password;
    
        @OneToMany(mappedBy = "person")
        Set<Author> Author;
    }
```

Author Class:

```
@Entity
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class Author {

    @Id
    private int id;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="Person_ID")
    Person person;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="Publication_ID")
    Publication publication;

    private String Date;

    private String Writerstatus;
}
```

Publication Class

```
@Entity
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Data
public class Publication {
    @Id
    private int id;

    private String publicationname;


    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "publication")
    Set<Author> author;
}
```

And the PublicationRepository

```
public interface ProjektRepository extends JpaRepository<Projekt,Integer> {
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public interface PublicationRepository extends JpaRepository<Publication,Integer> {
      @Query(value = "SELECT pub.* FROM author as auth INNER JOIN publications as pub ON auth.publication_id = pub.id WHERE auth.person_id = ?1", native = true)
      List<Publication> findAllPublicationsOfThisPerson(int personId);
}
```

Try this.

I would also recommend to annotate the entities with their table names:

`@Table(name = "publication")`

You use a manually build table for a Many-to-Many relationship `Author`
You could also delegate that to Spring Data Jpa by using `@ManyToMany` Annotation.

A good tutorial:
https://attacomsian.com/blog/spring-data-jpa-many-to-many-mapping